# how to declare variables based on other params in C++

Tags: c++

I have the below code (eg):

```
void Foo(int ip_selector)
{
    ipv4_hdr_t ipv4;
    ipv6_hdr_t ipv6;    
    {
        …
        if(ip_selector == 0)
            addStack(ipv4);
        else
            addStack(ipv6);
    }
{
        …
        if(ip_selector == 0)
            addStack(ipv4);
        else
            addStack(ipv6);
    }   
     …
}
int main() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        Foo(i);
    }
}
```

In the above code, addStack param depends on the selector param in Foo(). The above code works fine, but does to the scale it can grow, I do not want to add if ip_selector check everywhere in Foo() to see which arg to be passed in addStack(). I am trying to find a way to select either ipv4_hdr_t/ipv6_hdr_t without writing an if else condition. Infact, I dont even need the ipv6 declaration of ip_selector is 0 (vice versa for that matter)

Comment: you can use templates.

Comment: You can embed the two variables in a union as long as they are exclusive to each other.

Comment: @serge Thanks serge. But AFAIK, templates would help if ipv4_hdr_st/ipv6_hdr_st is a param of Foo() itself. How would template fix this case?

Comment: If you do everything twice anyway, why not have two separate functions?

Comment: @Raindrop7, that might work!. I will try this now.

Comment: @ Bo Persson, it is not just ipv4/ipv6. In future we might end up adding several other protocols and do not want to replicate the function.

Comment: Does not compile. Post a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to solve such a problem.

1.have a base class for your protocols, say `Protocol`.

2.derive your ip4/ip6/whateverelse classes from the base class.

3.create an array of available protocols.

4.use the selector to pick an array element.

```
class Protocol {
    virtual void addStack() = 0;
    ...
 };
 class Ip4Protocol : public Protocol {
     ip4_hdr_type hdr;
     void addStack(){...}
  };

vector<Protocol*> availableProtocols = {
    new Ip4Protocol(),
    new IP6Protocol(),
    ...
};
...
for (int i = 0; i < availableProtocols.size(); i++) {
    avalableProtocols[i]->addStack();
}
```

or you can probably use templates on the derived classes as well

```
termplate <class P> class IP : public Protocol {
      P hdr;
      void addStack()  {addGlobalStack(hdr)};
}
```

ther are tons of other possibilities as well.